# Django ImportError No module named report when I don't have anything named report at all

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm trying to put a url in my navigation as so:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'event' %}">Event Images</a></li>
```

my main urls.py has this line:

```
url(r'^event/', 'rma.event.view.index', name='event'),
```

but I get this error when rendering the page. I remove the `<li>` from the page and it displays fine.

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/rma/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('rma',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /soft/echostar/rich_media/rma/templates/rma/base.html, error at line 62
   No module named report
   52 :           


   53 :         </div>


   54 :       </div>


   55 :     </div>


   56 : 


   57 :     <div class="container-fluid">


   58 :       <div class="row">


   59 :         <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">


   60 :           <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">


   61 :             <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>


   62 :             <li><a href=" {% url 'rma.event.view.index' %} ">Event Images</a></li>


   63 :             <li><a href="#">Service Logos</a></li>


   64 :             <li><a href="#">Person Photos</a></li>


   65 :           </ul>


   66 :         </div>


   67 :         


   68 :         <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">


   69 :           <h1 class="page-header">{% block page_title %}Overview{% endblock %}</h1>


   70 : 


   71 :           <div id="page-content">


   72 :             {% block content %}Base.tpl Error: Content block not found!{% endblock %}          


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/soft/echostar/rich_media/rma/main/view.py" in index
  4.     return render(request, 'rma/main.html', {'test': 'hi'})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  509.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  387.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  296.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  285.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  100.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named report
```

Comment: Your usage of the url tag is fine, but Django is failing to import your URL conf. In your urls.py, do you have any imports or url patterns that refer to a `report` module?

Comment: Yep that was it, I had referenced some not yet created view named report that I had forgotten about. Removed that line and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the url tag is fine, but Django is failing to import your URL conf.

Check your urls.py for any imports or url patterns that refer to a `report` module.